# copying fastq information into a new fastq file

Tags: python, fastq

I am trying to write write a code that will open a fasta file and extract read name (title), sequence (seq), and quality scores (qual) from a different fastq file ONLY IF it is found in the fasta file, and write that fastq information into a new fastq file.  However, I am having trouble with the how to write this last part (I have bolded where I am having trouble in my code). Might someone know how to write this part, or where I can find the info on how to input this in python?

So far I have:

```
from sys import argv
from Bio.SeqIO.QualityIO import FastqGeneralIterator

script, merged_seqs, raw_seqs = argv
merged_from_raw = "merged_only.fastq"

merged_names = set() 
for line in open(merged_seqs): 
        if line[0] == ">":
                read_name = line.split()[0][1:] 
                merged_names.add(read_name) 

raw_fastq = raw_seqs

temp_handle = open(merged_from_raw, "w") 
for title, seq, qual in FastqGeneralIterator(open(raw_fastq)) :
        if title in merged_names:
                **handle.write() #this is where I don't know how to write what I need in python**
```

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have a specific reason to implement file parsing yourself, you would be better off using SeqIO parsers to handle your input and output files. Perhaps something like the following (caveat: I have never worked with Bio before, nor have I tested this code):

```
from sys import argv
from Bio import SeqIO

output_filename = 'merged_only.fastq'
merged_seqs, raw_seqs = argv[1:2]

# Get fasta iterator, and read source fastq file into a dict-like object
merged_names = SeqIO.parse(merged_seqs, 'fasta')
source_seqs = SeqIO.index(raw_seqs, 'fastq')

filtered_seqs = (source_seqs[record.id] for record in merged_names if record.id in source_seqs)
SeqIO.write(filtered_seqs, output_filename, 'fastq')
```

Comment: Thank you for this code, I am not that great at coding in python, so this was the only real way that I knew how to do it, but using SeqIO seems like a better option.  The only thing is when I run the code on a test data set, I receive an empty document. I know there should be 2 written sequences in the output, however it is empty, and not exactly sure why that would be

Comment: You could try printing `list(merged_names)` and `list(source_seqs)` to see whether anything has been read. My assumption that `record.id` is the same as `title` might be wrong.

Comment: printing list(merged_names) and list(source_seqs) showed that it was reading my source_seqs but not the merged_names (fasta) file. I was curious and tested it on a test fastq file (so both files were fastq instead of one fasta and one fastq). Doing this successfully wrote the output file, but its strange that this doesn't work with a fasta file. I will try to play with it some more, perhaps my test fasta file wasn't properly formatted.

in any case, thank you for the suggestion to use seqio, this was very helpful!

Comment: Try creating a fasta file using SeqIO.write() and then read it back.. Should work and you can compare the 2 fasta files.